# Binding a shortcut accross multiple files/screen Python3.3 Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am running a into a bit of a problem by over modulization in my current app. I trying to bind  a shortcut to the program but for the life of my I can't figure out where to bind it. I would prefer it work at all "screens" of the application and I will handle the saving and switching safely later. Any help would be appreciated. I also have a global file that contains all the global variables for all the files. So in short where would I place the bind and to what exactly. (Sorry for not including a small runnable sample but I can make one if need be.)

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, w, h, master=None):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk_screens = scr.GUIScreens(self)
        self.grid()

        # master.bind("Left",print("Something"))

        self.window_width = w
        self.window_height = h
        globals.window_width = w
        globals.window_height = h

        # print(window_width,window_height)
        # Application.bind('<<Return>>',Application.test(self,"enter"))
        print(Application)

        tk_screens.home_screen(True)
        tk_screens.query_screen(False)
        tk_screens.res_screen(False)
        tk_screens.settings_screen(False)
        tk_screens.customer_screen(False)


        # print(master.winfo_width())
        # self.update()

    def init_widget_state(self, dict, state):

        if not state:
            for i in dict:
                dict[i].grid_remove()
        else:
            for i in dict:
                dict[i].grid()

    def swap(self, old, new):
        for i in old:
            old[i].grid_remove()
        # self.query_screen()
        for i2 in new:
            new[i2].grid()

    def test(self,event):
        print("Clicked a button:"+event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = tk.Tk()
    main.wm_title("Title")
    main.geometry("1800x900")
    # main.state("zoomed")
    main.bind('<<Return>>',Application.test(self=main,event="enter"))

    main.update()
    globals.init()
    app = Application(master=main, w=main.winfo_width(), h=main.winfo_height())
    app.mainloop()
```

This is the seperate file that contains all the screens.

```
class GUIScreens():
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.frame = frame
        self.frame.bind('<Return>',lambda :main.Application.test(self,"enter"))


    def home_screen(self, state):
        self.frame.bind('<<Return>>',main.Application.test(self,"enter"))

        """This where I declare all the widgets for this "screen""""

        self.frame.bind('<F1>',print("Test"))

        main.Application.init_widget_state(self, globals.home_widgets, state)
```

PS. OS is Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bind_all` on your `Tk` instance to bind every widget to the return key:

```
main.bind_all("<Return>", event)
```

Additionally, you should check how you're using functions as parameters. Sometimes, you're correctly using `lambda`, but sometimes, you're not, just using the *return* value of the function, which defaults to `None`.

Comment: Completly missed that. Thanks and the whole lambda was just because I was trying multiple things but I got it sorted now